# Export animation from .dae to scenekit

Tags: scenekit, collada

On WWDC 2015 - Session 606 - Enhancements to SceneKit there was an Fox example project which is available to download.
Can anyone say what is the correct collada file setttings when exporting model with skeletal animation from 3D tool into .dae file? For example in the demo project there is a "walk.scn".
I used 3D tool (Cheetah3D) to make a simple model with simple skeletal animation and export it in .dae, but I can't get my model to be animated on the scene.

If I use non skeletal animation in 3D tool and export it in .dae then model animation on the scene works perfect.

Maybe someone succeed with exporting model with skeletal animation using another 3D tool like Blender?

Comment: Ok, I make it work but there is one bug – after applying animation the model on the scene changes it's position to (0,0,0)